# XSLT 2.0 performance of convert flat XML data to heirarchical?

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have data as follows:

```
<Root>
    <Node>
        <Region>Central</Region>
        <Provider>A</Provider>
        <Value>100</Value>
    </Node>
    <Node>
        <Region>Central</Region>
        <Provider>B</Provider>
        <Value>200</Value>
    </Node
    <Node>
        <Region>Central</Region>
        <Provider>B</Provider>
        <Value>250</Value>
    </Node>
    <Node>
        <Region>Eastern</Region>
        <Provider>C</Provider>
        <Value>50</Value>
    </Node>
</Root>
```

And trying to transform as:

```
<Root>
   <Region>
       <Name>Central</Name>
       <Provider>
           <Name>A</Name>
           <Item>
              <Value>100</Value>
           </Item>
       </Provider>
       <Provider>
           <Name>B</Name>
           <Item>
              <Value>200</Value>
           </Item>
           <Item>
              <Value>250</Value>
           </Item>
       </Provider>
    </Region>
    <Region>
        <Name>Eastern</Name>
        <Provider>
            <Name>C</Name>
            <Item>
                <Value>50</Value>
            </Item>
        </Provider>
    </Region>
</Root>
```

In the past I have used [Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html), but I am trying to use XSLT 2.0 construct `xsl:for-each-group` to accomplish the same thing without success so far.

Is it possible to use `xsl:for-each-group` to accomplish the above? How?

**Edit**

This is what I have so far, which appears to work.  But, I am not sure about efficiency - specifically does using such constructs force the parser to read the entire document and sort it?  The data coming in is already sorted the way I want.

```
<xsl:template match="Root">
    <xsl:element name="Root">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Node" group-by="Region">
            <xsl:element name="Region">
                <xsl:element name="Name">
                   <xsl:value-of select="Region" />
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="Provider">
                    <xsl:element name="Provider">
                        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                           <xsl:element name="Item">
                             <xsl:value-of select="Value" />
                           </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each-group>                       
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each-group>

    </xsl:element>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 always work on a full document tree so I don't understand your question. You are not doing any sorting anyway, only grouping. I wouldn't worry about performance unless you experience problems, and in that case you would need to profile your code and check which parts cause the problems.

Comment: As for your code, the grouping looks good, I would suggest to use literal result elements `<Region>...</Region>` instead of the wordy `<xsl:element name="Region">...</xsl:element>` or `<xsl:copy>` instead of the `<xsl:element name="Root">`, but that is mainly meant to save you from typing code or to have more flexibility than to solve performance problems.